# How to pass FBAccessToken to webview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, xcode5, facebook-sdk-4.0

In our app, we log users in using the FacebookSDK. We also have a web view which is currently asking the user to login AGAIN. What we are attempting to do is pass the access token in the url so that our rails server can identify the user, rather than having them login twice. In the FacebookSDK framework, I have found "accessToken" which should give us the ability to call the string and combine it with the url. Is this possible? I'm new to iOS development and I am hitting a couple of errors in this process.

```
NSString *url = @"http://example.com/?access_token=" + accessToken;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self.tempWebView loadRequest:request];
```

I have imported the Facebook file containing the method accessToken

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FBAccessTokenData.h>
```

Am I missing something important here?

I am presented with a Semantic Issue: 
    Use of undeclared identifier 'accessToken'

NOTE: We are not actually logging into Facebook, we are using OAuth w/facebook.

Thank you Stack! your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Passing the access token to the webview will not help. Of course you can't use an access token to log someone in. That would be a huge security hole if you could login as any user that authed your app

Comment: Why webview? May be you better need create same UI with Facebook API?

Comment: Is there something else that I would be able to pass? or is this a fault with the FacebookSDK in which we are not able to log the user into the UIWebView without directly asking them to login to Facebook again?

Comment: Cy-4AH, we are using the webview for fast iteration using rails, so we have a temporary webview where we are feature testing.

Comment: @WizKid we are using OAuth protocol for logging users into our application. we are not actually trying to log them into Facebook. does that clarify a little better?

Comment: If you use a Webview submit it as a Website and explain very clearly that it isn't a website

Comment: @dunbah Found any solution ? (please share)